# Why does it says that 'next' is not defined in redux middleware code. Is next method of middleware deprecated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting this error:

`index.js?dadc:6Uncaught TypeError: next is not a function`

Is the next method used by middleware in ReactJS deprecated or have I used it incorrectly?

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers , createStore } from 'redux';

const logger =(store) => (next) => (action) => {

    console.log('middle-ware called');
    next(action);

}

const reducer=(state ,action)=>{
    if(action.type=='INC'){
        console.log('a-----------------',action);
        return state+action.payload;
    }
    else
        return state; };

const store=createStore(reducer ,1 ,applyMiddleware(logger()));



store.subscribe(()=>{
    console.log('store changed',store.getState()) });

store.dispatch({type :'INC' ,payload : 10}); store.dispatch({type :'INC' ,payload : 10});
```

Comment: what happen if you `console.log` the value of `next` in `logger`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not working because you are passing to `applyMiddleware` the returned value of `logger()` with no arguments.

To fix it, you have to pass `logger` instead of `logger()` to `applyMiddleware()`.

You can read more about custom middlewares [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html)

Comment: I solved my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72978999/redux-middleware-with-configurestore-next-is-not-a-function with your soution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to pass an enhancer as middleware. Moving the enhancer from `middleware` to `enhancers` fixed the problem.https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#enhancers