# Redux middleware with configureStore: Next is not a function

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add a custom middleware to my Redux (I'm using it with `configureStore`)

```js
const reducer = {
    layout: layout,
    login: login,
    companies: companies,
    services: services,
    platforms: platforms,
    report: report,
    users: users,
    stats: stats,
    version: version,
}

const logger = store => next => action => {
    console.log('dispatching', action)
    let result = next(action)
    console.log('next state', store.getState())
    return result
  }

const store = configureStore({
    reducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger())
});
```

But I get `Uncaught TypeError: next is not a function`

Cannot find a working example with configureStore.

The packages that I'm using are:

```js
"react-redux": "^8.0.2",
"redux": "^4.2.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
```

## Update #1

I followed hint of

as following

```js
const reducer = {
    layout: layout,
    login: login,
    companies: companies,
    services: services,
    platforms: platforms,
    report: report,
    users: users,
    stats: stats,
    version: version,
    wizard: wizard,
}

const logger = store => next => action => {
    console.log('dispatching', action)
    let result = next(action)
    console.log('next state', store.getState())
    return result
}

const middlewareLogger = logger(store)(next)(action);

const store = configureStore({
    reducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(middlewareLogger())
});

export default store;
```

but i get

```js
src/reducers/index.js
  Line 33:40:  'next' is not defined    no-undef
  Line 33:46:  'action' is not defined  no-undef
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One minute after, I found solution, thanks to this post: [Why does it says that 'next' is not defined in redux middleware code. Is next method of middleware deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314057/why-does-it-says-that-next-is-not-defined-in-redux-middleware-code-is-next-me)

Error was I'm calling `logger()` instead of `logger`.

So, I did't pass any arguments to logger.

Final working code:

```js
const store = configureStore({
    reducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(logger)
});
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't match the question asked

Comment: My solution compiles, works and finally I got what I need.